# Validate age by date of birth using Enterprise Library Validation Application Block

Tags: validation, enterprise-library, validation-application-bl

I have the following situation: 
A domain model that has a property BithDay.
I want to be able to verify that the age (that will be computed accordingally to the birthday) is lower than 150 years.
Can I do that by using the built in validtors or I have to build my own?
Can someoane provide me an example of DomainValidator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`RelativeDateTimeValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664580.aspx) to validate an age based on a Birth Date.  For example:

```cs
public class Person
{
    [RelativeDateTimeValidator(-150, DateTimeUnit.Year, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, 
        0, DateTimeUnit.Year, RangeBoundaryType.Ignore,
        MessageTemplate="Person must be less than 150 years old.")]
    public DateTime BirthDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

// 150 Year old person
Person p = new Person() { BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-150) };

var validator = ValidationFactory.CreateValidator<Person>();
ValidationResults vrs = validator.Validate(p);

foreach (ValidationResult vr in vrs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(vr.Message);
}
```

This will print: "Person must be less than 150 years old."

Comment: Is there a way to use this tipe of validation relative to another property in object?

Comment: How can I add complex validation between objects? In this case I have to compute the age at the time when the person details were added in the database.Therefore I have another property of another object (the Person's parent in the hierarchy) that stores data regarding the date the object was added? Is there a way to compute age based on that value?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    [RangeValidator(0, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, 150, RangeBoundaryType.Exclusive,
        MessageTemplate="Person must be less than 150 years old.")]
    public int Age
    {
        get { return (DateTime.Now - this.BirthDate).Days / 365; }
    }
}
```